# PHP Google reCAPTCHA with AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have form in 100.php with ajax call to 200.php.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- include reCAPTCHA API JavaScript library given by Google -->
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

     <script type="text/javascript" 
     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {            
    $("#btn").click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();

        var myname = $("#name").val();
        var myaddress = $("#address").val();
        var yourData ='name='+myname+'&address='+myaddress; // php is expecting name and age
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          data:yourData,//Without serialized                
          url: '200.php',
          success:function(data) {
             if(data){
                $('#testform')[0].reset();//reset the form
                $('#result').html(data); // here html()
                //alert('Submitted');
             }else{
                return false;
              }                        
           }
         });

        });             
     });
</script>
</head>
<body>


    <form method="post" id="testform">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name"/> <br />
        Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="" id="address"/>
        <!-- 
            place for the reCAPTCHA widget div with your site key 
            data-theme="dark" attribute - gives dark version
        -->
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeJ8h8TAAAAAMS9nQX89XccpsC-SDeSycipiaHN"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Send" id="btn"/>
    </form>
    <div id='result'></div>

</body>
```

200.php does validate captcha and diaplay name and adddress user entered. But my problem is that when I entered name and address, click on captcha. Captha is also validated and shows as in my screenshot. but name and address is not shown on the page. You can also check yourself here: http://raveen.comlu.com/100.php

I am new to Ajax call by PHP. I googled and I can troubleshoot by firebug. Can you say what I am doing wrong here? and steps to troubleshoot by firebug like to check if my ajax call is done, etc? thanks for your help.

Note: when I put all these code in one page without using ajax call. it works fine!!!!! I want this happens without page reload....

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PKcB.jpg)

200.php

```
<?php
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');

    if( isset($_POST['ok']) ){

        if( isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) ){
            $secret = "6LeJ8h8TAAAAAB3IFQVQEaoApFe6lvq4Wxlktvn1"; //your secret key
            $response = null; //empty response
            $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret); //check secret key is present

            $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] );

            //$response variable will report back with "success"
            if( $response!=null && $response->success ){
                echo "<h1>Hi ". $_POST['name']. " from ". $_POST['address']. ", thanks for submitting the form!</h1>";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<h1>Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.</h1>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Are you using Google recaptcha V2?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, sir I have no idea. how do I know that?

Comment: I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul sir, thanks a lot.I need to read your answer few times and test it. Then I will ask you if I have any questions about.But for now, I have another question that is not related to this question.But I cannot ask it in SO as a question is not code related. I am new to PHP. I would like to know how people make photos galleries like this: http://toursinsrilankabathiya.com/gallery.php Only by hard coding via PHP or using any libraries?Is there any way which I can know which libaray they have used like looking page source?Are there any popular libraries I can use with little PHP knowldge?

Comment: These kinds of photo galleries can be build using PHP and jQuery. It's completely based on your requirement because if you're writing code on your own you can customize it, tweak it as per your requirement. However, there are several jQuery plugins are available which will make your work much easier. Here's a quick [jQuery plugin search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=image+gallery+jquery+plugin),

Comment: @RajdeepPaul. your information is very useful. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few errors in your code, such as:

- Look at the following two statements,

  ```
  if( isset($_POST['ok']) ){...
  ```

  and

  ```
  var yourData ='name='+myname+'&address='+myaddress;
  ```

You're not sending any variable named `ok` to **200.php** page, so the control won't even enter the `if` block.

- You're validating reCaptcha in the wrong way. From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify):

> If your website performs server side validation using an AJAX request, you should only verify the user’s reCAPTCHA response token (**g-recaptcha-response**) once. If a verify attempt has been made with a particular token, it cannot be used again. You will need to call **grecaptcha.reset()** to ask the end user to verify with reCAPTCHA again.

So you have to use **grecaptcha.getResponse()** to get the user's response.

And as a sidenote use **grecaptcha.reset()** to ask the end user to verify with reCAPTCHA again.

Your **jQuery/AJAX** script should be like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {            
        $("#btn").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            var recaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();

            var myname = $("#name").val();
            var myaddress = $("#address").val();
            var yourData = {name: myname, address: myaddress, recaptchaResponse: recaptchaResponse};
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: yourData,
                dataType: 'html',
                url: '200.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    // reset form
                    $('#testform')[0].reset();

                    // display data
                    $('#result').html(data);

                    // reset the reCaptcha
                    grecaptcha.reset();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    // error
                }
            });
        });             
    });
</script>
```

And on **200.php** page, process your AJAX data like this:

```
<?php

    //your site secret key
    $secret = '6LeJ8h8TAAAAAB3IFQVQEaoApFe6lvq4Wxlktvn1';

    if(isset($_POST['recaptchaResponse']) && !empty($_POST['recaptchaResponse'])){
        //get verified response data
        $param = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$_POST['recaptchaResponse'];
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents($param);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

        if($responseData->success){
            // success
            echo "<h1>Hi ". $_POST['name']. " from ". $_POST['address']. ", thanks for submitting the form!</h1>";
        }else{
            // failure
            echo "<h1>You have incorrect captcha. Please try again.</h1>";
        }

    }else{
        echo "<h1>Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.</h1>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Sir, your solution works well. Thanks. But I have few questions. Please correct me if I understand correct. 1) in 200.php, I do not need require_once('recaptchalib.php'); no longer because functionality  of that class is done by ourselves now? grecaptcha.getResponse() & grecaptcha.reset() are provided by this javascript library <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>?    2) http://raveen.comlu.com/100.php this is with your code working well.

Comment: When I click Send, I can see Chrome tab is loading few seconds? So I uncommented this line //$('#testform')[0].reset();//reset the form ,,,, to check ajax call? As I know if the page reloads, all input data are lost. But in this case, they are not lost. So I can know ajax call working. Am I doing right to check ajax call? How to check it in firebug?

Comment: @LenaStein 1) There's no need to use any library here, Google reCaptcha script will take care of everything. 2) Yes, `grecaptcha.getResponse()` and `grecaptcha.reset()` are provided by this javascript library. 3) You can go to *console* panel of firebug to check AJAX request/response.